# Issue in Coverting zlib compressed base 64 string to Uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64

In one my current project, I have to parse base 64 string, which is encoded and stored by flex(Adobe Flash) application. By discussing with flex dev team I found that they storing image string in bitmap format so I assumed it is a pixel representation.

**So, first question from me is, in above mentioned case can I directly convert raw data into UIimage using base64 decoding class or I have to use CGBitmapContext ?**

However, currently I have implemented below mentioned code for conversion.

`
 //Convert to Base64 data

```
NSData *decodedData = [QSStrings decodeBase64WithString:_settingSerializedImage.currentValue];


NSError *error = nil;
NSData *unCompressedData = [decodedData bbs_dataByInflatingWithError:&error];



NSData *dataImage = [NSMutableData new];
NSUInteger bytePosition = 0;
uint8_t * bytes =  malloc(5);
[unCompressedData getBytes:&bytes range:NSMakeRange(unCompressedData.length-3, 3)];

bytes = OSSwapBigToHostInt16(bytes);
int width = (int)bytes;

[unCompressedData getBytes:&bytes range:NSMakeRange(unCompressedData.length-5, 5)];

bytes = OSSwapBigToHostInt16(bytes);dataImage = [unCompressedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, (unCompressedData.length -5))];

NSUInteger length = [dataImage length];
unsigned char *bytesData = malloc( length * sizeof(unsigned char) ); [dataImage getBytes:bytesData length:length];UIImage *imgScreenShot = [ScreenshotPortlet convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:bytesData withWidth:width withHeight:height];`
```

below is the method for converting raw data in image using core graphics

```
+ (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer
                            withWidth:(int) width
                           withHeight:(int) height {

 char* rgba = (char*)malloc(width*height*4);
for(int i=0; i < width*height; ++i) {
    rgba[4*i] = buffer[4*i];
    rgba[4*i+1] = buffer[4*i+1];
    rgba[4*i+2] = buffer[4*i+2];
    rgba[4*i+3] = buffer[4*i+3];
}
//


size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rgba, bufferLength, NULL);
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    return nil;
}

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;

CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width,
                                height,
                                bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel,
                                bytesPerRow,
                                colorSpaceRef,
                                bitmapInfo,
                                provider,
                                NULL,
                                YES,
                                renderingIntent);

uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

if(pixels == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    return nil;
}

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                             width,
                                             height,
                                             bitsPerComponent,
                                             bytesPerRow,
                                             colorSpaceRef,
                                             bitmapInfo);

if(context == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error context not created");
    free(pixels);
}

UIImage *image = nil;
if(context) {

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGImageRelease(iref);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);


if(pixels) {
    free(pixels);
}   
return image;
```

}

[Here is the output I'm getting , a distorted image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEr3.png)

So can anyone suggest me better solution or tell if I'm on right direction in it or not? Thanks, in advance :)

For reference  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwnE2tR5be-XZVZ1X3VZajFqMW9XNmVzRHBhdlVHSlVuTUNZ) you can find original base 64 string

Comment: There is just method `+ [UIImage imageWithData:]`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that also but, it is giving me nil image object. After failure of that I have tried this implementation. Can you please review my implementation and give any suggestion ? thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you provide original base64 string? Because it's actually hard to tell with which data you are working now. May be it's image, may be it is compressed image, may be it's pdf.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I have included base 64 file link in my question. plz check

Comment: you just only need to decode base64string to uiimage ..?

Comment: @vaibhav, yes first of all, I tried simple decoding method only, but I was getting nil image object as I mentioned in above comment.  Have you reviewed attached base 64 string ?

Comment: @user3011809 yes i saw but it is just only a matter to convert base64string to image and vice versa so i have a solution for you.

Comment: You mean first I have to convert base64string to data and the data into base 64 string?  Can you please try implementing it in sample and share it here if you can?  it will be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @user3011809 see and and let me know ..

Answer (score 2):

**To convert image to base64string:**

```
- (NSString *)imageToNSString:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    return [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
}
```

**To convert base64string to image:**

```
- (UIImage *)stringToUIImage:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this but it is not working for me. It is giving me nil image object. Thanks btw.

Comment: then there is probably something wrong in you string ..just help yourself :)

Comment: Actually this base 64 string is compressed one, so I'm uncomressing it using some zlib library extension. so should there be issue related to it?

Comment: can you please share how you are getting string inside `NSString *object` so i could see this and help you if i ..

Comment: As mentioned in code above I am getting base 64 string from webservice in _settingSerializedImage.currentValue variable, which i am decoding to nsdata and then uncompressing it.