# Swift encoding/decoding images for JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, encode

I'm kinda new to swift and i need some help with encoding some image, putting it in a JSON and after retrieving it, decoding it back to NSData and recreating the image in an UIImage view controller.
I've found this post [Convert Image to Base64 string in iOS + Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift/11251478#11251478) but i get stuck with this part:

`let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)`

because the fromRaw method is not available anymore.

Thanks in advance

Later edit:
I'm using swiftyJson to parse the array and i'm getting the image data like this:

```
var base64String = arrayJson[0]["photo"].stringValue
var imageString = base64String as NSString
```

and after that i'm trying to decode it like this:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

I've also tried with the rawValue instead of IgnoreUnknownCharacters. Both return nil. Also tried with the base64String instead of imageString. Same thing.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following instead to make a base64 encoded string to an UIImage:

```
 //base64 string to NSData
 let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

//NSData to UIImage
var decodedIamge = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
```

`NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!` now is changed to `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)`

For more encode/decode details, you can visit this post: [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift)

Comment: yes, the decodedData is nil. Basically, i'm putting in a mysql db through a JSON this value:let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 50)
        let encodedImage = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

Comment: Have you tried to print the base64String or imageString?

Comment: yes.....the imageString starts like this:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QCMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAASgEbAAUAAAABAAAAUgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAWgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAOgAQA

Comment: You might not encode your image correctly, you can try to covert your string to an image using this online convert: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Comment: i'm encoding it like this : let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 50)
let encodedImage = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

Comment: you can print your `encodedImage`(which is a string), and compare if it match the 'base64String` during your decode process. Also, you can encode your image in http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/, and use the string from converter, make sure you get rid of `data:image/png;base64` from the raw output. You can try this base 64 string from my gists file: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ziyang0621/60c18dcb7c5bfa1eb762/raw/90c46541deab749f45d60110bfc17b9cd3b55575/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 3):

To encode an image:

```
let image = UIImage(...)
let quality = 1.0
let data: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, quality)!
```

To decode an image:

```
let decodedImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why these methods return nil for you could be that your base64string is an URL and Filename safe variant, meaning character 62 (0x3E) is replaced with a "-" (minus sign) and character 63 (0x3F) is replaced with a "_" (underscore) as noted here [base64 alphabet](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html)

Try replacing character `_` with `/` and character `-` with `+` in your string.

You could use the following code:

```
base64string = base64string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
base64string = base64string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "_" , withString: "/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Also be aware of the correct length of the string. it has to be a multiple of 4 
- take a look at this answer [padded string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208107/5050044).

Answer (score 0):

NSData Class Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDataBase64DecodingOptions

NSDataBase64DecodingOptions :

```
struct NSDataBase64DecodingOptions : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt)
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var IgnoreUnknownCharacters: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions { get }
}
```

Have you tried one of the followings :

- `let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)!)`
- `let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)`

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? im facing the same thing. @AdrianStoicescu

Comment: hmmm...i'm not sure but as far as i remember i abandoned the method. If you want, show me your code and maybe i can help