# initWithBase64EncodedString return nil

Tags: objective-c, base64

My resultString is 'PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIH...c3BvbnNlPgoK' and when i am decoding it shows me decodedData as nil.

NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:resultString options:0];

I also tried this string with https://www.base64decode.org/ , 
it successfully shows results.

What wrong here in decoding ?

Comment: Did you even tried to search it on SO? :| Hope this link will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7

Comment: Yes i first tried to search and then i post.

Answer (score 10):

Probably you have some invalid characters in your string, like padding new lines. Try to pass [NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatabase64decodingoptions/nsdatabase64decodingignoreunknowncharacters?language=objc) option instead of `0`.

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:resultString options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

Comment: I was getting <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1c04610c0] = { leaf, size = 442, buf = 0x105829a00 }> issue. Then I converted my data from API to string and reconverted back to data (for further decryption) using the above code. While passing 0 with the above code I was getting nil. Passing NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters worked.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly your string is not valid Base64, but that it is "close enough" that base64decode.org accepts it. The most likely cause is that you've dropped a trailing `=`. base64decode.org is tolerant of that, and just quietly throws away what it can't decode (the last byte in that case). `NSData` is not tolerant of that, because it's not valid Base64.

base64decode.org is also tolerant of random non-base64 characters in the string and just throws them away. `NSData` is not (again, sine it's invalid).

Comment: True. NSData regards non-padding base64 string as "invalid Base-64". Anyone feels needed you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406482/nsdata-wont-accept-valid-base64-encoded-string/21407393 for adding the paddings.

Answer (score -1):

Try this! Simple solution :) Must need Foundation.framework. By default initWithBase64EncodedString method returns nil when the input is not recognized as valid Base-64. Please check your string is a valid Base-64 type or not!

```
    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"eyJuYW1lIjoidmlnbmVzaCJ9" options:0];
    NSError *dataError;
    NSDictionary* responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:decodedData
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&dataError];
   if(dataError == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Result %@",responseObject);
   }
```

Comment: Have you added foundation framework with ur project? Result {
    name = vignesh;
}

Comment: @KrishSolanki, Please provide sample encoding string.